# Why compiler force me to specify unsafe in c#

Tags: c#, unsafe

I know I've to compile with Unsafe Option to use unsafe code in C#
Consider the following

```
static void foo()
{
    int a = 5;
    int* p = &a;
}
```

the above code won't compile unless I mark method as unsafe or wrap above statements inside unsafe block.

Am curious why compiler force me to do this? is there any technical reason behind this?

Comment: My guess is that Microsoft put it there to make sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: That is what my assumption too, but am looking whether any technical reason behind it?

Comment: @Sriram: Some pointer operations can break type-safety -- pointer casting and pointer arithmetic.  I guess the designers felt it was easier to detect *all* pointers, than only the specific cases that subvert typing.

Comment: Because the pointer doesn't give you just access to the "a" variable, it gives you access to *everything*.  Including the method return address and stack frames of other methods.  You can use it to make code jump to arbitrary locations, an exploit called "smashing the stack".  Add `*(p+17) = 0;` for example.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree, but as your ex:`*(p+17) = 0;` I can do this after mentioning unsafe right? then what is point in mentioning?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : If you would read the link provided in Austin's comment you would see that the creators of the language put it in for the sole purpose of making you decide to use unsafe code. Without the keyword any idiot could put use a pointer and not know how dangerous it can be.

Comment: What is the point of *not* mentioning that you are exposing yourself to crashes and exploits?  What are you trying to hide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19105/The-Unsafe-way-of-doing-it) with nice detailed explanation -

> In C and C++, developers have direct access to memory. When a piece of
>   C or C++ code requests access to a block of memory, it is given the
>   specific address of the allocated memory, and the code directly reads
>   from and writes to that memory location. The advantage to this
>   approach is that direct access to memory is extremely fast and made
>   for efficient code. There are problems, however, that outweigh the
>   benefits. The problem with this direct memory access is that it is
>   easy to misuse, and misuse of memory causes code to crash. Misbehaving
>   C or C++ code can easily write to memory that has already been
>   deleted, or can write to memory belonging to another variable. These
>   types of memory access problems result in numerous hard-to-find bugs
>   and software crashes.
>
> The architecture of the CLR eliminates all of these problems by
>   handling memory management for you. This means that your C# code can
>   work with variables without needing to know details about how and
>   where the variables are stored in memory. Because the CLR shields your
>   C# code from these memory-related details, your C# code is free from
>   bugs related to direct access to memory.
>
> Occasionally, however, you need to work with a specific memory address
>   in your C# code. Your code may need that extra ounce of performance,
>   or your C# code may need to work with legacy code that requires that
>   you provide the address of a specific piece of memory. The C# language
>   supports a special mode, called unsafe mode, which enables you to work
>   directly with memory from within your C# code.
>
> This special C# construct is called unsafe mode because your code is
>   no longer safe from the memory-management protection offered by the
>   CLR. In unsafe mode, your C# code is allowed to access memory
>   directly, and it can suffer from the same class of memory-related bugs
>   found in C and C++ code if you're not extremely careful with the way
>   you manage memory.

Answer (score 2):

The unsafe keyword denotes an unsafe context, which is required for any operation involving pointers.

You can use the unsafe modifier in the declaration of a type or a member. The entire textual extent of the type or member is therefore considered an unsafe context.

From the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

A good explanation is given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sebby1234/archive/2006/04/05/565090.aspx)

Comment: but why compiler force me to do that. it can find by own that my method uses pointer right?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sebby1234/archive/2006/04/05/565090.aspx